# InvalidArgumentError Traceback (most recent call last)

Tags: graph, execution, traceback, invalidargumentexception

I've created a simple CNN with two main labels. The imput_shape was changed from 300 to 224 and the batch_size is 128. What am I supposed to do?

After entering this code:

```
history = model.fit(
            train_ds,
            validation_data=val_ds,
            epochs = 20,            
            verbose = 2)
```

I got following error message:

```
Epoch 1/20
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [63], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 history = model.fit(
      2             train_ds,
      3             validation_data=val_ds,
      4             epochs = 20,            
      5             verbose = 2)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py:52, in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     50 try:
     51   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 52   tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     53                                       inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     54 except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     55   if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
      return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
      app.launch_new_instance()
    File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 846, in launch_instance
      app.start()
    File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 677, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 199, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 601, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1905, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 80, in _run
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 471, in dispatch_queue
      await self.process_one()
    File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 460, in process_one
      await dispatch(*args)
    File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 367, in dispatch_shell
      await result
    File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 662, in execute_request
      reply_content = await reply_content
    File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 360, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
    File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py", line 532, in run_cell
      return super().run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2863, in run_cell
      result = self._run_cell(
    File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2909, in _run_cell
      return runner(coro)
    File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\async_helpers.py", line 129, in _pseudo_sync_runner
      coro.send(None)
    File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3106, in run_cell_async
      has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name,
    File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3309, in run_ast_nodes
      if await self.run_code(code, result, async_=asy):
    File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3369, in run_code
      exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "C:\Users\local_sms92\Temp\ipykernel_43944\602300899.py", line 1, in <cell line: 1>
      history = model.fit(
    File "C:\Users\sms92\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\sms92\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1650, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "C:\Users\sms92\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1249, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\sms92\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1233, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\sms92\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1222, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\sms92\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1024, in train_step
      loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "C:\Users\sms92\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1082, in compute_loss
      return self.compiled_loss(
    File "C:\Users\sms92\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\compile_utils.py", line 265, in __call__
      loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "C:\Users\sms92\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 152, in __call__
      losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "C:\Users\sms92\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 284, in call
      return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\sms92\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 2098, in sparse_categorical_crossentropy
      return backend.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(
    File "C:\Users\sms92\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\backend.py", line 5633, in sparse_categorical_crossentropy
      res = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
Node: 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits'
Received a label value of 2 which is outside the valid range of [0, 2).  Label values: 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 1
     [[{{node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_38939]
```

(I've already tried to modify the imput_shape to 224, as recommended on other platforms, but this didn't work)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your output label to `0 & 1`, instead of `1 & 2`, since the error message shows that:

> Node: 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits'
> Received a label value of 2 which is outside the valid range of [0, 2).